# Problem consuming IIS hosted service - locally and remotely

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, visual-studio-2012

I build 2 services for the project I'm currently working on.

1) a simple client-server request service using basicHttpBinding

2) a callback dataservice using WSDualHttpBinding

with some twiddling I was able to host both in IIS and I can visit both :/Service.svc in my browser locally as well as on another machine that shall interact with both services as well.

here is the app-config section for the callback dataservice

```
    <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="myBehavior">
        <clientVia />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IDataService">
              <security mode="None">
                <message negotiateServiceCredential="false" clientCredentialType="None" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://<address>:50111/Service.svc/service"
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IDataService" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior"
            contract="CallbackService.IDataService" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IDataService">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

the basicHttpBinding looks quite similar - only to another port

I set IIS to anonymous authentication .. User IUSR, no password ..

Originally it worked locally - but from the remote computer I received authentication errors .. so I tweaked some more - and now I get a timeout even locally .. though Visual Studio interacts with the service reference to both services just fine.

How do I get the service "to cooperate" again

And I'm at my wits end - any help greatly appreciated!?

Edit: first problem solved - local communication restored

```
public ClientCallbacks myCallbacks=new ClientCallbacks();      
public DuplexChannelFactory<IDataService> channelFactory { get; set; }
public IDataService channel;

public int connect() {
    WSDualHttpBinding binding = new WSDualHttpBinding() 
        { Name = "WSDualHttpBinding_IDataService" };
    this.channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IDataService>(
        mainForm.dbCommunication.myCallbacks,
        binding,
        new EndpointAddress("http://<address>:50111/Service.svc/service"));
    this.channel = this.channelFactory.CreateChannel();
...
...
channel.AddListener(int-parameter); // announce new callback-partner
...
...
 this.newListe = this.myCallbacks.receivedTaskList; //get Tasklist over callback
```

This works locally - but calling it remotely I get a "new" error

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException:
  The caller was not authenticated by the service. ---> 
  System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied
 because authentication failed.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault
    (Message message, EndpointAddress target)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody
    (Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

And again I struggle to find a clue / solution .. I set IIS authentication to anonymous ... but it seems the communication is blocked before that point is reached .. What do I have to do to reach the service from a remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that we should provide the credentials to have the client authenticated by the server-side. which sort of credentials should be supplied relies on the binding configuration of the server-side.
By default. The security mode of the `WsDualhttpbinding` is configured with Message security mode, and the client credential type is Windows.
These below code snippets are equivalent.

```
WSDualHttpBinding binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
```

---

```
WSDualHttpBinding binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = WSDualHttpSecurityMode.Message;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
```

From your code snippet, I didn’t see your configuration of the server-side. If Windows credential is required, please consider the below code segments.

```
//ChannelFactory<IService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory(...);
            channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
            channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "123456";
            IService svc = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: thx for your answer - thought the server configuration was explained via app.config listing .. I didnt program any credential checking and thought <security mode="None"> would take care of that ...

Comment: But the app.config belongs to the client-side. We should configure the binding to be consistent with the server-side. Is it automatically generated by Adding Service Reference tool?

Comment: Yea - was auto-generated by "Add Service Reference" - and I found the root cause for a lot of my problems ... Server didn't "find" database because the Server was excluded from the DNS group - after using the IP-address those "time outs" magically disappeared ..